# How do I execute a Linux utility from within PHP with shell_exec() when I get the error "command not found"?

Tags: linux, shell, shell-exec

I've installed a linux utility ( [optipng](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) ).

It works fine when called from the command line like so: `$ optipng image_name.jpg`

If I try to execute it from within PHP like this `shell_exec( 'optipng image_name.jpg' );` ...I get the error `optipng command not found`

I also get the error `sudo: optipng: command not found` when I try to run it from the command line using `sudo`.

When I installed this utility I used `configure` and `make`.

What do I have to do to get this working from `shell_exec()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by PHP not recognized where is the location of optipng

You should try in linux console :-

```
whereis optipng
which optipng
```

Once you have the absolute path,
replace the `optipng` in your `shell_exec`